Blender 4.1 - Video Editing Filter to remove Combing and perform edge smoothing?
I am new to Blender, and I am trying to use the video editor to create some MP4s out from some old VOB captures that were done years ago from VHS with a DVD converter program/device.
The captured images had (what I suppose are) artifacts derived from interlacing, though I don't know whether the VOB video files are actually interlaced.
I can import the VOB files into the sequence editor and create an MP4 movie from them.  However, if I chose the "Deinterlace Movie" setting in the Movie Strip settings, then the entire render is completely messed up (static and horizontal spinning).  If I don't choose that then everything comes out okay, but the combing artifacts from the original are still there as shown in this magnified image.
I have tried the a few of the filters that came with Blender by default, but nothing seems to smooth or average this out.  Should it?  Is there a way to smooth these out with some sort of averaging filter?  Maybe an add-on filter?
Thanks in advance!

